# Get Avarage network trafic data in MB

Tags: wireshark, packet-tracer

Currently i am using a MiroTik router, that has build in a data trafic graph.
Its werry well working, but it cant be saved and it shows only last 24h/ last week/ mounth /year.

I would like to have some data when and how much is the network in use.I use wireshark to scan the network for trafic/packages. Now i would like somehow to get a graph of average data usage per minute/hour/day.

[MikroTik Graph](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/images/thumb/a/a4/Graphing-mem.png/650px-Graphing-mem.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous solutions out there for monitoring.
You can use [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/), [MRTG](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/), [PRTG](https://www.paessler.com/prtg), or [any other solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems) out there.

The most common method of statistics collection is via SNMP but also NetFlow is supported on MikroTik RouterOS.

It's up to you really to choose whatever solution fits your need better.